# aligning in relative view, in xml android

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I am using a RelativeLayout on the screen. I have RadioButtons docked to the right side of the screen and I want to align the TextViews to the left of the RadioButtons.

So here is an example of my text view:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/error1" />
```

I am not sure if it aligns them to the center of the RadioButton and not below because that doesn't work for me. I hate Eclipse's (adt) xml gui, and editing in xml file because I don't get what I want. Is there an easier gui, xml editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no better xml gui editor for android for now. IntelliJ Idea 10.5 doesnot even have screen preview only xml editor.

Now the trick to use the screen gui editor and xml editor. You start with basic gui editing by screen editor that comes with ADT and then to fine tune either use properties or raw xml editor.

As per what you want for above problem. Here is the soln:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For creating this i didnot edit the xml file myself. I just used the gui screen editor that comes with ADT. Here are the steps

- I created the xml with Relative layout via wizard that is also part of ADT.
- Added `RadioButton` from left pane and dragged it towards the right edge of the screen till i can see two green anchor points appear and in the yellow info appeared stating the properties for alignment.
- Then I added `TextView` and drag towards the left till I see green anchor points.
- Then I dragged the right edge of `TextView` towards the `RadioButton` till I see green anchor and the correct `layout_toLeftOf` property in the yellow info box.

Comment: isnt it too messy. will proportions change when testing on other devices..It is also so messy to drag them down..I cant always place them near the center of the radiobutton..isnt there alignCenterOF

Comment: Well it will work fine on different screen sizes. As you can see there is no hard-coded dimensions mentioned above. Since I dont know what will be your final layout. The above one anchors to parent top only. You can anchor to parent bottom also to look it more centralized vertically. And you can use the `gravity` for aligning content with in a widget/view. For aligning the view it self there are `layout_centerInParent`, `layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_centerVertical`.

Comment: I think I will put a tablelayout inside..and put two rows..that will have to align them...what do you think

Comment: Are you using this layout as component for List item for ListView or it is the layout of the activity? What exactly is your layout should be?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to toLeftOf radioButton1 instead of radioGroup?

Also, change the layout_width to wrap_content instead of fill_parent.

Comment: true..sorry..will it center the text view beside it?